# TeamCity : Exclude merge request build from a specific branch

Tags: gitlab-ci, teamcity

I have a merge request build job in TeamCity, which runs whenever there is a merge request to any branch in Gitlab.

We have got different branches such as **Production, staging, edge & testing**.

The VCS Configuration is given below

[image]

I want to exclude this job for any merge request to the **testing** branch in Gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

Which TeamCity version are you using? Latest version (2022.04.4) allows to filter MRs via target branch

[image]

Comment: We are using old TeamCity version 2019.2

Comment: Under which settings, I could find the above posted screen shot ?

Comment: It's screenshot of Pull Requests build feature. Maybe this could help https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/pull-requests.html